# Running a Database on LSF platform

Tags: database, postgresql, redis, cluster-computing, lsf

I have to run some benchmarks on a a computer cluster which uses LSF as a platform to submit jobs. 
I need to run these Benchmarks on different databases. Some of them need to run a server before listening to connections from the client (Like PostgreSQL or Redis).

Is there an way to run the Server on the Cluster using  LSF?

Answer (score 0):

Batch schedulers are all about controlling what program/process can use what resource (cores, mem, licenses, etc).  So long lived services like databases are started outside of the batch schedulers control.

If the databases live just the lifetime of the job, then start and stop them in your job script.